# showing an inner product space isn't a bounded operator

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have H is an inner product space with inner product:

$(\alpha,\beta)=\int_{0}^{1} \alpha(t) \beta(t) dt$.

I define $T : H \to H$ by $T(\alpha)=\alpha'$.  By considering $\alpha_n$ given by $\alpha_n(t)=t^n$ for positive integers n, I'm supposed to show that T is not a bounded operator.

Well in order to show it is a bounded operator, I need to show that $[T(\alpha),T(\alpha)] \leq K^2(\alpha,\alpha)$.  so do I need to show that $[T(\alpha_n(t)),T(\alpha_n(t))] \leq K^2(t^n,t^n)$??

Comment: Compute $( T(\alpha_n), T(\alpha_n) )$ and compare it with $(\alpha_n, \alpha_n)$ to show that no $K$ works uniformly.

Answer (score 2):

The statement "$T$ is a bounded operator" can be restated as

> There exists a constant $K>0$ such that $[T(\alpha),T(\alpha)] \leq K^2(\alpha,\alpha)$ for all $\alpha \in H$

The **negation** of this statement, i.e. "$T$ is not a bounded operator", can be restated as

> For every constant $K > 0$, there exists an $\alpha \in H$ such that $[T(\alpha),T(\alpha)] > K^2(\alpha,\alpha)$

This latter statement is the statement that you must prove.

---

**In response to your comments:** Note that for all $n$, we have
$$
(\alpha_n,\alpha_n) = \int_0^1 (t^n)(t^n)\,dt
= \int_0^1 t^{2n}\,dt = \left.\frac{t^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\right|^1_0 = \frac{1}{2n+1}
$$
On the other hand,
$$
(T(\alpha_n),T(\alpha_n)) = \int_0^1 (nt^{n-1})(nt^{n-1})\,dt
= n^2\int_0^1 t^{2n-2}\,dt = \left.n^2 \frac{t^{2n-1}}{2n-1}\right|^1_0 = 
\frac{n^2}{2n-1}
$$

Comment: The statement for the negation should end with $K(\alpha,\alpha)$, no? (otherwise, you can just scale $\alpha$ until $[T(\alpha,\alpha)] > K$.)

Comment: @BaronVT whoops good catch

Comment: So if I compute $(T(\alpha),T(\alpha))$ and get $(n\alpha_{n-1})^2$ 

and $(\alpha,\alpha)=t^{2n}$

I would then get $((n\alpha_{n-1})^2 > K^2(t^{2n})$.  How would I know this is true if I don't know what $(\alpha_{n-1})^2$ is?

Comment: $(T(\alpha),T(\alpha))$ and $(\alpha,\alpha)$ should always be **numbers**, that is, scalars rather than vectors. You're computing something incorrectly.

Comment: See my latest edit.